# "Log out (username)" logs out all users

Tags: macos, login

When I click on "Log out User A" in the Apple menu, then click the Log Out button, the current user is logged out.  After I get back to the user selection page, I can pick another logged-in user (call them User B), but almost as soon as I see their desktop they start logging out as well.  By the time I return to the user selection page, *all* users including User C and User D are also logged out.

I saw this a few times when using they keyboard shortcut (<kbd>CMD-SHIFT-Q</kbd>) for logout, where I'd quickly switch after logging out a user and see the "log out" popup prompt for an unrelated user, but I figured that somehow the keyboard input was being relayed to a background user's account (which would also be crazy, I grant you, but less crazy than this).

I think it started happening when I upgraded to 10.10, but I wouldn't swear to it.  It's happening almost every time I log anybody out now, and I'd really like to make it stop.  Help?

Comment: Does everyone get logged out and the system stays at the login prompt, or does the system reboot? Everyone would get logged out during a reboot, which is the only thing I can think of.

Comment: No reboot.  The really crazy part is that everybody isn't just logged out unceremoniously, it's actually the prompt (which you can't always see, because you're not at User B's desktop, unless you click through to User B right away) followed by the 60-second countdown, followed by logout. This is driving me nuts.

Comment: Still happening, not always getting the prompt but I'll log out one user, then switch to another, then everything freezes for 2 or 3 seconds and I'm back at the user selection screen with all logged-in users logged out.  This is really getting infuriating.